# What's the difference between the latin square and the matrix?

Tags: matrices, latin-square

What's the difference between the latin square and the matrix?

Comment: A Latin square is a square matrix satisfying certain conditions.

Comment: Why not just consult the wiki article on latin squares it seems straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Latin square is a special type of matrix.

Latin square has to be a square while matrix do not have to be.

Also, for latin square, $n$ symbols are required and there are restriction that each symbol appears exactly once in each row and column.